# How to read the ASCII value of a character into a variable in C?

Tags: c

If I have a string: 
`char cInputString[] = "Hello World";`
And I want to iterate through it and get the ASCII value of each character, how do I write this value to a variable in the code that I can use instead of to the terminal? So on the first pass I have a variable `ASCIIValue = 72;`

Comment: Hint: `char` is an integer type!

Comment: int H = (int) cInputString[0]; and similarly for the rest.

Comment: A "for" loop would be a good place to start.

Comment: @Ritesh The cast is not required.

Comment: @Cool Guy: They type of cInputString is char array, so char H = cInputString[0] would have been natural operation. But we are tyring to put that cInputString[0] in int, that can raise compiler warning. And its always safe to be explicit so that reader knows what is happening.

Comment: @Ritesh "_that can raise compiler warning_" -- Nope. Try it. The reason? Read Olaf's comment above.

Comment: For me char is one byte data and int is 4 byte data. when we do int H = cInputString[0], its implicit conversion that is happening and its safe to do that. Some compiler like this some may give you warning. Moreover my point was more towards readability.

Comment: @Ritesh The only rare situation where a `char` will not fit in a `int` is when `char` is unsigned and they have the same width.  Compilers/platforms rarely use this model.  The overwhelming situation is that any `char` will fit into an `int`.  An explicit cast implies something special is happening.  Assigning a `char` to an `int` is common.  It is not wrong to cast, yet it detracts from visual flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable that you want is **asciiValue**. **Here is your code:** (I tested)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int * getASCIIValue(char *array) {
    char c;
    int i, ascii;
    int result[100];


    for(i=0; array[i]; i++) {
        ascii = (int)array[i];
        result[i] = ascii;
    }

    return result;
}

void main()
{
    char cInputString[] = "Hello World";
    int asciiValue[100], i;


    int *arr = getASCIIValue(cInputString);

    for(i=0; i<strlen(cInputString); i++) {
        asciiValue[i] = arr[i];
    }

    for(i=0; i<strlen(cInputString); i++) {
        printf("%d", asciiValue[i]);
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: The auxiliary array `result[]` serves no benefit and it limits correct usage to a string of size 100 or less.   Simply `printf("%d", cInputString[i]);` would do.

Comment: @chux, he wants a variable, not print out on terminal.

Comment: As the title says "How to read the ASCII value of a character ...", that implies the OP wants to read some output such as print out on terminal.  Code already has the variable `cInputString[]` with ASCII values in it.  Copying to `result[]` gives OP 2 copies.

Answer (score 2):

```
for ( size_t idx = 0; idx < strlen(cInputString); idx++ ) {
    printf("ascii of %c = %d \n",cInputString[idx],cInputString[idx]);
}
```

Comment: Isn't `size_t` instead of `unsigned int` better?

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII value would be the value of each character in the string. Simply retrieve them by indexing the string.

```
for ( unsigned int idx = 0; idx < strlen(cInputString); idx++ ) {
    ASCIIValue = cInputString[idx];
}
```

Comment: Isn't `size_t` instead of `unsigned int` better?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.